# How can i change ClearCanvas DesktopForm application menu's visibility to false

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, clearcanvas

i try to write a PACS application over ClearCanvas opensource sources. But i can everything over DestopForm only _mainmenu's visibility turn into  false stage.

```
// _mainMenu

this._mainMenu.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
this._mainMenu.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None;
this._mainMenu.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
this._mainMenu.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this._mainMenu.Name = "_mainMenu";
this._mainMenu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(792, 24);
this._mainMenu.TabIndex = 4;
this._mainMenu.Text = "menuStrip1";
this._mainMenu.Visible = false;
```

[image]

i can do every form events. But visibility make me too sense.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to DesktopForm.cs
and comment out

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the menu model.
/// </summary>
public ActionModelNode MenuModel
{
   get { return _menuModel; }
   set
   {
     //    _menuModel = value;
     //    BuildToolStrip(ToolStripBuilder.ToolStripKind.Menu, _mainMenu, _menuModel);
   }
 }
```